# Change Angular output directory from wwwroot to another folder in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

Currently my ASP .NET project with angular frontend (inside one Project) is putting the Angular output folder (dist content) inside /wwwroot folder when published.

```
Website_ASP.exe
web.config
wwwroot
    index.html
    scripts ....
    etc..
```

Now I don't want the output inside wwwroot folder at all. this way it's just not tidy and clean. I want it inside a different folder in root like `ClientApp/dist` and serve that when opening base url : `http://localhost:5000`.

I don't know which and how many files I need to edit for this to happen, I've tried setting a staticfile directory on said folder but then the Angular doesn't work properly.

Currently:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

and I have tried :

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
       Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp")),
RequestPath = "/"
});
```

How many files do I need to edit in Angular and ASP to completely change the frontend path to a different folder outside wwwroot, or at the very least inside wwwroot/dist.

Comment: Keep in mind that previously the .NET application was hosting the angular application. With the latest .NET templates it's the other way around: The angular application is hosting the .NET application (using the SpaProxy Nuget). So if you want the SPA in the ClientApp folder, you will need to use the `UseSpa` middleware once again

Comment: Can you elaborate? how can the frontend framework host the backend? and what If I'm not using SPA?
Plus I have a hard time understanding what useSpa does, since my app runs as a SPA just fine without it, so I don't know what's the point of using it and don't see a difference.

Comment: I don't yet have much experience with the [latest dotnet template](https://github.com/dotnet/spa-templates/tree/main/src/content/Angular-CSharp) since I barely use it, however it contains the [proxy.conf.js](https://github.com/dotnet/spa-templates/blob/main/src/content/Angular-CSharp/ClientApp/proxy.conf.js) which indicates what requests must be forwarded to the API and what requests should be handled by the angular app itself. However in the previous dotnet template there was the `UseSpa` middleware which did the opposite

Comment: Oh right. Yea I understand what you mean. but that was exactly my problem, the former angular template used spa and the output folder was inside a dist. now with the recent template and proxy.conf there's no spa settings that you could change the SPA dir in. and the output path changed. hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My test sample:

**Program.cs or your Startup.cs file**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

namespace AngularSPA
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            //app.UseStaticFiles();
            // ==========> change here
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp", "dist")),
                RequestPath = ""
            });
            app.UseRouting();


            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "AngularSPA": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "progress": false,
            //"outputPath": "dist",
            //  ======> change here
            "outputPath": "../ClientApp/dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "oidc-client"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "AngularSPA:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "AngularSPA:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.js"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AngularSPA:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-server",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "AngularSPA",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

**.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:44440</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="7.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- ==============> add code here to include client\dist folder -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />

    <Content Include="ClientApp\dist\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --configuration production" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

#### My test result

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try once I get the chance.

Comment: Thank you. works nicely. finally got the time to try it.  just why is it that I have to put /index.html at the end of url? doesn't work if I don't. shouldn't the flat localhost:5000 default to index.html? seems odd.

Comment: Hi @Swrena, maybe we can create a simple spa project and deploy it for test. If they have different behavior, you can create a new post, maybe others who know it can help you.

Comment: This shouldn't be a big issue. hopefully I can resolve it by browsin' a bit. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (**.NET 7**) the Angular app is published to a folder inside `dist` folder. (It was because how we have setup the Angular projects/libraries). So the `index.html` was inside `dist/Portal.App/index.html`.
Related segment from the **angular.json**,

```
...
         "options": {
            "progress": false,
            "outputPath": "dist/Portal.App",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",

...
```

Now in the `Program.cs`, I had to add/change `UseDefaultFiles`, `UseStaticFiles`, `MapFallbackToFile` middlewares to serve the static files over **IIS**, by creating an instance of `PhysicalFileProvider`.

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//==========Changed here=================
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(app.Environment.WebRootPath, "Portal.App"));
app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = "",
    DefaultFileNames = new[] { "index.html" }
});
//==========Changed here=================
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = ""
});

app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

//==========And here=================
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html", new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = ""
});

app.Run();
```

That's it. Haven't really changed the `.csproj` file or added a `web.config`. But I'll leave a link to the `.csproj` file [here](https://gist.github.com/nishanc/16f6ba22146dcde8311ea56a6f9cafda#file-portal-app-csproj).