# Copy Output of Npm Command to Publish Directory using MSBuild

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild

I have a very simple task for MSBuild to accomplish. I run `npm run build` which drops the static files of a website into the `staticsite` folder of my project, in the same directory as the .csproj file. I have chained two  commands to copy these outputs to the output/publish directories after the build. I do not see the folder in the publish directory.
What's the magic MSBuild command here? Using .net core 5.0.

```xml
<Target Name="NpmInstall" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="npm install" />
        <Exec Command="npm run build" />
</Target>

<Target Name="CopyStaticOutput" AfterTargets="NpmInstall">
  <ItemGroup>
      // I've tried every alternative like <None Update="..." CopyToPublishDir> etc.
      <None Include="staticsite\**">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: If you want to hook into the copying that is already performed, then after `Build` is too late. The copying has already been completed. If your `staticsite` has no dependency on the project and just needs to be part of the oputput, then use `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"`.

Comment: [Could you check the answer first ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75506597/7687666) It  will useful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken when trying to get MSBuild to do this in a first-class "Copy" task. The correct way to copy a file or directory is to `xcopy` in a PostBuild target:

```
    <Target Name="CopyToOutput" AfterTargets="NpmBuild">
      <Exec Command="xcopy /i /s /e /y $(ProjectDir)staticsite $(OutDir)staticsite" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CopyToPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
        <Exec Command="xcopy /i /s /e /y $(ProjectDir)staticsite $(PublishDir)staticsite" />
    </Target>
```